# Could not connect to Realm Object Server 2.0

Tags: realm, realm-object-server, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I install ROS on my server, but when I called  `ros start` and it will running at my server, here is the log:

```
login as: root
root@*.*.*.*'s password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-109-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Welcome to Alibaba Cloud Elastic Compute Service !

root@iZwz940pq66re8qvh8adzuZ:~# ros start
info: Loaded feature token capabilities=[Sync], expires=Wed Apr 19 2017 22:15:29 GMT+0800 (CST)
info: Realm Object Server version 2.5.1 is starting
info: [sync] Realm sync server started ([realm-core-4.0.4], [realm-    sync-2.1.10])
info: [sync] Directory holding persistent state: /root/data/sync/user_data
info: [sync] Operating mode: master_with_no_slave
info: [sync] Log level: info
info: [sync] Download log compaction is enabled
info: [sync] Max download size: 131072 bytes
info: [sync] Listening on 127.0.0.1:35571 (sync protocol version 22)
info: Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080
```

But when I entered the address in the browser, It told me that I could not connect.And I use Realm Studio to connect it also tell me that could not reach the server, did i forget something steps? Maybe my server's security policy forbide the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per to the log description, Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080.
Please ensure you've allowed TCP port 9080 in your ECS security group.
[image]
For detail steps, please refer the document 
[Add a security group rule](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25471.htm)

Comment: Thx, I find it's the problem of Alibaba ECS, not mine